# Packer: How do I create an AWS AMI with multiple block devices having different kms keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am trying to use packer version 1.3.2 to bake an AMI with multiple block devices where each block device is encrypted with a different KMS key, which is different then the KMS key used to encrypt the boot device.

At first I started to think that maybe this isn't supported by AWS; however, using AWS console, I was able to launch an EC2 instance with and AMI having previously encrypted volumes and add another volume that used a different KMS key. Then create an AMI from it. I then used the new AMI to launch another EC2 instance and the different KMS keys were maintained. This is because it did create a new snapshot for the additional volume with the different KMS key.

I have attempted so many different variations using the amazon-ebs builder with combinations of ami_block_device_mappings in conjunction with launch_block_device_mappings. Any combination at best generates the final volume snapshots tied to the AMI using the boot KMS key. I noticed that if I specify the alternate kms_key_ids in the launch_block_device_mappings like the following:

```
"launch_block_device_mappings": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "volume_size": "{{user `var_volume_size`}}",
      "delete_on_termination": true,
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_arn_var`}}",
      "encrypted": true
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdc",
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "volume_size": "{{user `varlog_volume_size`}}",
      "delete_on_termination": true,
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_arn_varlog`}}",
      "encrypted": true
    }, ...
```

It creates temporary snapshots with the alternate kms key but they are replaced with new ones that are encrypted with the boot kms key for the final AMI, regardless of whether I also include ami_block_device_mappings or not. Even if I set delete_on_termination to false for the launch...

I then looked that this from another angle by trying to create the snapshots from EBS volumes separately from the amazon-ebs builder. Using the amazon-ebsvolume builder, I created empty EBS volumes:

```
"type": "amazon-ebsvolume",
...
      "ebs_volumes": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "volume_type" : "{{user `var_volume_type`}}",
      "volume_size": 10,
      "delete_on_termination": false,
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_arn_var`}}",
      "encrypted": true,
      "tags" : {
        "Name" : "starter-volume-var",
        "purpose" : "starter"
      }    
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdc",
      "volume_type" : "{{user `varlog_volume_type`}}",
      "volume_size": 5,
      "delete_on_termination": false,
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_arn_varlog`}}",
      "encrypted": true,
      "tags" : {
        "Name" : "starter-volume-varlog",
        "purpose" : "starter"
      }    
    },...
```

And then created snapshots from them and then attempted to use the snapshot_id of those instead of creating volumes inline in the amazon-ebs

```
"launch_block_device_mappings": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "volume_type" : "{{user `var_volume_type`}}",
      "snapshot_id": "snap-08f2bed8aaa964469",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdc",
      "volume_type" : "{{user `varlog_volume_type`}}",
      "snapshot_id": "snap-037a4a6255e8d161d",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    }
  ],..
```

Doing this I get the following error:

```
2018/11/01 03:04:23 ui error: ==> amazon-ebs: Error launching source instance: InvalidBlockDeviceMapping: snapshotId can only be modified on EBS devices
```

I tried repeating the encryption settings along with the snapshot_ids:

```
      "launch_block_device_mappings": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "volume_type" : "{{user `var_volume_type`}}",
      "snapshot_id": "snap-08f2bed8aaa964469",
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_arn_var`}}",
      "encrypted": true,
      "delete_on_termination": true
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdc",
      "volume_type" : "{{user `varlog_volume_type`}}",
      "snapshot_id": "snap-037a4a6255e8d161d",
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_arn_varlog`}}",
      "encrypted": true,
      "delete_on_termination": true
    }
  ],...
```

This results in a different error:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterDependency: The parameter KmsKeyId requires the parameter Encrypted to be set.
```

But I clearly have "encrypted": true

I am running out of ideas and feel it's possible, just apparently not smart enough to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Came here because I had the same problem. I fixed this by moving the device to `/dev/xvdf`.

Digging into this further the source AMI I was using has the following block mappings associated with it, these ephemeral disks were not displayed in the console so it took me a while to workout what was going on, a big clue was the fact I could mount the disk even before I defined it (I originally defined it as an AMI mapping rather than launch in error but had the mount in my scripts already)

```
Block devices: /dev/sda1=snap-0b399e12978e2290e:8:true:standard, /dev/xvdb=ephemeral0, /dev/xvdc=ephemeral1
```

I notice you have not listed the source AMI but hopefully this helps